# Consider $f(x) = \frac{2x^3-1+\sin x}{x^2-3}$. Show that $f (x) < 2x$ for most negative values of $x$.

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Consider $$f(x) = \frac{2x^3-1+\sin x}{x^2-3}$$ Show that $f (x) < 2x$ for most negative values of $x$.

How do I start this/ what concepts does this questions test?

Comment: What do you mean by *most*?

Comment: Do you actually mean _negative_? The function is _decreasing_, so a comparison to $2x$ doesn't make that much sense...

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin{x}<=1$$ for every real number x, so we have $$f(x)<=\frac{2x^3}{x^2-3}$$ when $$x<-\sqrt{3}$$ or $$x>\sqrt{3}$$

when x does not equal to zero, we have $$\frac{2x^3}{x^2-3}=\frac{2x}{1-\frac{3}{x^2}}$$

also, $$\frac{2x^3}{x^2-3}=\frac{2x}{1-\frac{3}{x^2}} < 2x$$ when $$x<-\sqrt{3}$$,

as $$0<1-\frac{3}{x^2}<1$$ when $$x<-\sqrt{3}$$

so

$$f(x)<2x$$ when $$x<-\sqrt{3}$$

this is only my thought